# Store Large Amount of Info Using Classes

Tags: java, class

I want to get various information from the user. Eg. I want to get their forname,surname,address. I have a class to do so. But I shall be reading in alot of information of many users.

For example. User1 =; User2 =; all the way up to lets just say 200 different people.

My question is, if my class name is People.
Do I have to do this everytime?(I cant see this being the only way)

```
People user1 = new People(joe, bloggs, world);
People user2 = new People(mary, bloggs, universe); etc.
```

How would I go about doing this. I was thinking of writing it out to a .txt file in that order but then I dont know how I would read it in/modify it if a user wanted to change his/her address.

EDIT:

```
public static ArrayList<People> person= new ArrayList<People> ();
```

How do I add multiple new people to the array list and how do I know which position they are in?

Can anyone help me with this or set  me on the right track. Like I said Ill have to be able store alot of info and access it to modify it
Thanks.

Comment: Class names should be singular.

Comment: On semantics, you should call your ArrayList `people`, not `peoples`. People is already a collective plural. That people list should contain persons, not people. You're "creating a new person", not "a new people". People is a collection of persons.

Comment: You're coming to the right conclusions but these are pretty common problems with standard solutions. If you are building an application, try to use an existing framework and/or common application architecture patterns.

Comment: If you use a Map of a key such a a String to a Person you don't need to know where the entries are.  BTW 200 is not large.  one million might be considered large, one billion might be considered huge.

Answer (score 5):

You need to an *an instance of the class* to the ArrayList:

```
people.add(new Person(...));
```